# How to disable mediascanner-service?

Tags: upstart, 14.10

I've installed `ubuntu-sdk` and it depends among others on `mediascanner2.0`. I generally despise all such scanners/trackers and I'd like to disable it. But I can't find a way.

The config is in `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/mediascanner-2.0.conf`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To disable for all sessions:

```
sudo sh -c "echo manual >> /usr/share/upstart/sessions/mediascanner-2.0.conf"
```

To disable for your user only:

```
echo manual >> ~/.config/upstart/mediascanner-2.0.override
```

Comment: But upstart doesn't know `mediascanner-2.0` service. Anyway, I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: Make sure you run initctl stop without sudo. As a last resort, run `pkill mediascanner-service-2.0`.

Comment: Killing it is not an option, there is a `respawn` line in the config. Anyway, creating `config.override` with `manual` worked, thanks. It's a better solution than adding it to the main config.

Comment: And how can this be done in Ubuntu 15.10 with systemd?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you will not miss the "service" of mediascanner :o), just remove/purge it from installed packages:

> sudo apt-get purge mediascanner2.0

And you can also purge the libmediascanner:

> sudo apt-get purge mediascanner2.0 libmediascanner-2.0-0

libmediascanner comes together with mediascanner2 in Ubuntu update. It is the [Access library for the mediascanner's index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mediascanner2.0)